# Azure SQL DB throwing "This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database"

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have an ASP.NET MVC application migrated to Azure. Mostly it's running fine but in some pages following error is thrown and hence no data is fetched:

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable
>   to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original
>   database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed
>   from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.: Login
>   failed for user ''.

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: I guess you should post some of the ASP.Net code that's throwing this error.